# Как сделать что-то при нажатии на определенную колонку в DBGrid?

Tags: dbgrid

Как сделать что-то при нажатии на определенную колонку в `DBGrid`?

Comment: Язык какой?

Answer (score 1):

Если ты имеешь ввиду заголовок колонки (title) в Delphi, то можно реализовать сортировку:

```
procedure TForm1.dbgItemsTitleClick(Column: TColumn);
begin
 case Column.Index of
    1: begin /*второй столбец, поле дата*/
        DataModule1.ADOQuery1.Sort := 'date_s ASC'; /*сортировка по возростанию*/
    2: begin /*третий столбец, поле имя клиента*/
        DataModule1.ADOQuery1.Sort := 'name_client DESC'; /*сортировка по убыванию*/
 end;
end;
```

А вообще придумывай сам, главное - ты можешь сопоставить индекс колонки и соответствующего поля в таблице (запросе).